# How to add class to random element in pure JavaScript and set value to another element

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, random

my code
[My code use](https://jsfiddle.net/Shiva002/pstor5xz/8/)

```js
var lights = document.getElementsByClassName("light");
  var previousRandomLight = null

  function repeatOften() {
    if (previousRandomLight) previousRandomLight.classList.toggle('select')
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (lights.length - 1)) + 0;
    var randomLight = lights[random];
    randomLight.classList.toggle('select');
    previousRandomLight = randomLight;
    setTimeout(repeatOften, 1000);
    
  }
  
  repeatOften();
```

```html
<div class="">
  <p id="Customer" class="Customer"></p>
</div>
<div class="Master">
  <div class="top">
    <ul>
      <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/01.png" value="text1" alt="text1"></li>
      <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/02.png" value="text2" alt="text2"></li>
      <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/03.png" value="text3" alt="text3"></li>
      <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/04.png" value="text4" alt="text4"></li>
      <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/05.png" value="text5" alt="text5"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

now I need to be transferred value to the Customer field with each time added to the SELECT class

Like the code below :

```
<!-- output Simple --->
<div class="">
<p id="Customer" class="Customer">text3</p>
</div>
<div class="Master">
<div class="top">
<ul>
  <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/01.png" value="text1" alt="text1"></li>
  <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/02.png" value="text2" alt="text2"></li>
  <li class="light select"><img src="./pic/Gallery/03.png" value="text3" alt="text3"></li>
  <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/04.png" value="text4" alt="text4"></li>
  <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/05.png" value="text5" alt="text5"></li>
</ul>
```

But I did not know how to do that please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really clean in my opinion but it works:

```js
var lights = document.querySelectorAll(".light");

function repeatOften() {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (lights.length)) + 0;
  var randomLight = lights[random];
  lights.forEach((light) => {
    light.classList.remove('select');
  });
  randomLight.classList.toggle('select');
  setTimeout(repeatOften, 1000);
}

repeatOften();
```

```css
.select {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <p id="Customer" class="Customer"></p>
</div>
<div class="Master">
  <div class="top">
    <ul>
      <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/01.png" value="text1" alt="text1"></li>
      <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/02.png" value="text2" alt="text2"></li>
      <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/03.png" value="text3" alt="text3"></li>
      <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/04.png" value="text4" alt="text4"></li>
      <li class="light"><img src="./pic/Gallery/05.png" value="text5" alt="text5"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```